Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1
flutter error
I already tried to type flutter doctor in command prompt, however it just closes itself automatically. I literally don't know what's wrong as all my friend don't face this issue. I also installed and uninstalled flutter  multiple times but the problem is still not solved. I also watched all tutorials on youtube and nothing works. Please help me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try using the command prompt instead of powershell. And have you followed all the steps (most importantly setting the path) in the instructions at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=download#install-the-flutter-sdk
